# Words or phrases that indicate the opposite of a goal or target, meaning This is something to avoid, as it opposite of my desire

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

_____ - noun or adjective: indicating something to avoid, something opposite of what I want, something repulsive.

Example 1: 
My business's TARGET customers are Baby Boomers because they spend all their money.
Conversely, my business's _____ customers are Millennials because they complain and buy very little.

Example 2:
I do sprints in my exercise routine because my GOAL body is lean and agile, like Usain Bolt.
I don't lift heavy weights because because my _____ body is too bulky, like the strongman who played The Mountain in Game of Thrones.

I searched for:
- antonyms of "goal"/"target"
- synonyms of "undesirable", "reject"

I considered: 
- "antitarget" but it's a scientific phrase for another application
- "undesired", "unwanted" ... etc which would work if there is nothing more specific
- "reject" is the best word I can come up with so far

Please let me know if there are synonyms.

Comment: I don't think you will find a word quite like that. We would tend to rephrase, e.g. *because I don't want my body to get too bulky* or *we don't target Millenials because...* / *we are not so interested in Millenials because...*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps simplistically, the opposite of *target* is [**nontarget**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nontarget):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : not being the intended object of action by a particular agent
>   // effect of insecticides on *nontarget* organisms
>   // More than 200 deaths were *nontarget* animals, including foxes, opossums, raccoons, skunks and a bear.
>   — Sophie Lewis, *CBS News*, "Trump administration reauthorizes use of "cyanide bombs" to kill wild animals," 8 Aug. 2019

So, in one of the example sentences:

> Conversely, my business's *nontarget* customers are Millennials because they complain and buy very little.